# Using explode arrays in foreach and only last array Inserted into table, how does arrays work?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I get a text from html-form, didnt mention it here, but it looks like:

- John:John
- Mike:Mike
- Root:Admin

Here is my php code:

```
   $text = explode("\n", $_POST["info"]); 
// - get data from html form and //explode it to pieces
    print_r($text);
// result is: Array ( [0] => John:John [1] => Mike:Mike [2] => Root:Admin )
    foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
      $val = explode (":", $value);
// want to explode it to pieces, result must be 0=>John 1=>John, 0=>Mike 1=>Mike, [0]=>Root [1]=>Admin
$sql = "INSERT INTO `redtable`(`NAME`,`NAME2`) VALUES('$val[0]','$val[1]');";
    }
```

When this code runs, it inserts into database only the last line, which are (Root:Admin), why it doesn't inserts John:John, Mike:Mike ...?
Where is the mistake?

Here is the result of echo $sql:

```
INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('John','John ');INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('Mike','Mike ');INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('Root','Admin');
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mysql";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "red";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$pieces = explode("\n", $_POST["info"]);
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
  $val = explode (":", $value);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('$val[0]','$val[1]');";
echo $sql;
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "Days left updated";
} else {
  mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Have trying using if-else statements, like this:

```
# code...
  $val = explode (":", $value);
  #  print_r($val);
  if (1 == 1) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('$val[0]','$val[1]');";

  }
  else {
  echo "esle";
  }

}
```

The same result, only the last line have been inserted to the DB.

GUYS, If SOMEONE NEED THE WORKING SOLUTION WATCH @Matt Rabe answer - working like a charm, you need just replace the brackets!

Comment: With your current code, it should not insert _anything_. You need to show us more code.

Comment: Guessing: Because you're executing the query outside of the loop, so it will only have the last values from the last SQL statement your loop sets

Comment: Your code as it currently stands is a big security risk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Are you inserting inside your loop or outside? If outside then you are always overwriting $sql so only the last value is used.

Comment: How could it be out of the loop, if: foreach {$sql=....} ??? its inside of the loop

Comment: You are just setting and overwriting a string, nothing with the database.

Comment: If i'm executing it outside of the loop, how can I execute it inside of the loop? Because right now the $sql is inside the foreach , where is the mistake?

Comment: What does `echo $sql` look like?   Also for troubleshooting, add the `or die(mysqli_error($db));` to the query and print out the error if it exists

Comment: I have updated the question with the echo $sql result....

Comment: The SQL is right .. This is a database issue ..  What does `mysqli_error($your_connection)` show?

Comment: Or throw this at the top of your page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: It shows nothing, no error at all, I have tried mysqli_error.... and ini_set..... nothing.

Comment: Put if and else statements in foreach. This is not good suggestion but a way to work with current situation.

Comment: and what condition you seggest me to use in if-else statements? because I really don't get it how to use it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Baker is right - you are **executing** your sql outside of your foreach loop. You are **defining** the $sql var inside your foreach, but the actual execution of it (`$conn->query($sql)`) occurs outside of the foreach.

Change this:

```
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
  $val = explode (":", $value);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('$val[0]','$val[1]');";
echo $sql;
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "Days left updated";
} else {
  mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

To this:

```
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
  $val = explode (":", $value);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `redtable`(`IGNAME`,`IGPASS`) VALUES('$val[0]','$val[1]');";
echo $sql;

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "Days left updated";
  } else {
    mysqli_error($conn);
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
}
```

Your code has numerous issues beyond this, but this should address your stated question.

Comment: You're the first one who give me the example where I'm not inside the loop, thank you for that! I will try it in a minute!

Comment: you're an awesome human being! This code is worked like a charm. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: The key is to understand that, with the code as you had it, you were merely setting then overwriting a variable - your SQL - *not* writing to the database. That was happening once, outside the loop, with the last-written version of the SQL variable.

Comment: hey, can I ask you an offtop question? How sum two values from two different arrays and assign the result to the variable? I get the 0 result all the time, sample $arr1[1]//equal 10;  $arr2[1]//equal 20;When I do $sum = $arr1[1] + $arr2[1] // I get 10, not 30. Why?

Comment: cant find the answer on google, for real, searching about 1.5 hours. And Stackoverflow blocks me from asking questions.